# xcodebuild showsdks after installing xcode 9 beta in macos high sierra shows iOS 10.3 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to use iOS 11 SDK to build my app from command line. I have updated my macbook to mac os high sierra 10.13 and downloaded the xcode 9 beta. Also, I installed all the command-line tools and do not have any other versions of xcode installed.

When i type xcodebuild -showsdks i get

```
iOS SDKs:
iOS 10.3                        -sdk iphoneos10.3

iOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - iOS 10.3            -sdk iphonesimulator10.3

macOS SDKs:
macOS 10.12                     -sdk macosx10.12

tvOS SDKs:
tvOS 10.2                       -sdk appletvos10.2

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - tvOS 10.2           -sdk appletvsimulator10.2

watchOS SDKs:
watchOS 3.2                     -sdk watchos3.2

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - watchOS 3.2         -sdk watchsimulator3.2
```

I would like to use iOS 11 SDK instead of 10.3 to build from command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get iOS 11.0 SDK shown from "xcodebuild -showsdks" after I removed the xcode app from applications and re-installing it again.